# Combine characters and output to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I have a quick question, is there a way to have python combine a range of characters, combine them, then put them into a text file?

What I mean is, if I have the characters, "a", "b", "3", "F", "@", etc, is there a way to combine them in various ways to make, "abF", "F@b", "3F@ab", etc and then print them each on a separate line of a text file?

so far, what I've got is this:

```
lst = ("ab@F3")
list1 = list()
for ch in lst:
    list1.append(ch)
    print(list1)
```

I would like it to be able to output something like, "abF3" AND "3Fab" AND "Fb3a"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why `@` is not included in the last example?

Comment: You realize that there are 3905 possible permutations of any length for those 5 characters?

Comment: Basically you want all permutations for every element in the powerset of your list?

Comment: @ShashankGupta: I don't think he wants that; he just wants either all 120 4-element permutations, or all 120+120+60+20+5=325 N-element permutations for any N in [1, 5]. Either way, it's a whole lot more reasonable than what you're suggesting.

Comment: @abarnert Yeah my math was off. :P Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, after I only got 153 results from my solution I was supremely confused, heh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for n in range(1,5):
        for p in itertools.permutations('ab@F3',n):
            print(''.join(p), file=f)
```

based on above but with some fixes

Answer (score 2):

From your sample output, it looks like you want all 120 of the 4-element permutations of the 5-element set. That's simple with [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
list1 = list(itertools.permutations(lst, 4))
```

You also seem to want them in random order, but that's easy:

```
random.shuffle(list1)
```

If you want all permutations of *any* number of characters (well, any number from 1 to 5 inclusive), you just chain together the `permutations` for each number:

```
perms = (itertools.permutations(lst, n) for n in range(1, 6))
list1 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(perms))
```

There are 120+120+60+20+5=325 of these. And again, if you want them in random order, just `shuffle` them.

Almost anything reasonable that you want to do will be easy to do—but until you know, and can explain to a human, what it is that you actually want, you won't be able to explain it to Python either.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what you mean, but I guess this is what you want:

```
import itertools

chain = itertools.chain(*(itertools.permutations(chars, n) for n in xrange(1, len(chars) + 1)))
print ' AND '.join('"%s"' % ''.join(x) for x in chain)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from itertools import permutations
chars = 'ab@F3'
for r in range(len(chars)):
    for p in permutations('ab@F3', r+1):
        print ''.join(p)
```

You'll get every permutation of those characters.  In this example, there are 325 permutations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have no idea what this is trying to do, but whatever it is, it's doing it wrong. You're trying to joining each 2-element permutation with each number from 1 to 5. Why?

Comment: Thanks @abarnert!  I dropped the 2nd parameter of `permutations` down into the `join` call.  Corrected, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One liner (list comprehension) approach (because I don't want to add a duplicate answer)

```
import itertools
my_chars = "ab3F@"
print [''.join(p) for i in range(1, len(my_chars)+1) for p in itertools.permutations(my_chars,i)]
```

Comment: You just took my two-liner and turned it into one longer-than-80-character line. What's the point of that?

Comment: Haha, I didn't see your answer before writing mine. But, mine isn't exactly a replica of yours. Atleast better than the other duplicate answers. :|